# Python Data Frame: Create New Column Based on Values in a String Column and a Float Column

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following Python data frame below.  The "Flag" field is my desired column I want to create with code.

[image]

I want to do the following:

If "Allocation Type" is Predicted AND "Activities_Counter" is greater than 10, I want to create a new column called "Flag" and label the row with 'Flag'

Otherwise, leave the Flag row blank.

I use the following code to identify / flag where "Activities_Counter" is greater than 10... BUT I don't know how to incorporate the "Allocation Type" criteria into my code.

```
Flag = []

for row in df_HA_noHA_act['Activities_Counter']:
    if row >= 10:
        Flag.append('Flag')
    else:
        Flag.append('')

df_HA_noHA_act['Flag'] = Flag
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add new condition with `&`. Also faster is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = (df_HA_noHA_act["Allocation Type"] == 'Predicted') & 
       (df_HA_noHA_act['Activities_Counter'] >= 10)
df_HA_noHA_act['Flag'] = np.where(mask, 'Flag', '')
```

---

```
df_HA_noHA_act = pd.DataFrame({'Activities_Counter':[10,2,6,15,11,18],
                              'Allocation Type':['Historical','Historical','Predicted', 
                                                  'Predicted','Predicted','Historical']})
print (df_HA_noHA_act)
   Activities_Counter Allocation Type
0                  10      Historical
1                   2      Historical
2                   6       Predicted
3                  15       Predicted
4                  11       Predicted
5                  18      Historical

mask = (df_HA_noHA_act["Allocation Type"] == 'Predicted') & 
       (df_HA_noHA_act['Activities_Counter'] >= 10)
df_HA_noHA_act['Flag'] = np.where(mask, 'Flag', '')
print (df_HA_noHA_act)
   Activities_Counter Allocation Type  Flag
0                  10      Historical      
1                   2      Historical      
2                   6       Predicted      
3                  15       Predicted  Flag
4                  11       Predicted  Flag
5                  18      Historical
```

Loop slow solution:

```
Flag = []
for i, row in df_HA_noHA_act.iterrows():
    if (row['Activities_Counter'] >= 10) and (row["Allocation Type"] == 'Predicted'):
        Flag.append('Flag')
    else:
        Flag.append('')
df_HA_noHA_act['Flag'] = Flag
print (df_HA_noHA_act)
   Activities_Counter Allocation Type  Flag
0                  10      Historical      
1                   2      Historical      
2                   6       Predicted      
3                  15       Predicted  Flag
4                  11       Predicted  Flag
5                  18      Historical
```

**Timings**:

```
df_HA_noHA_act = pd.DataFrame({'Activities_Counter':[10,2,6,15,11,18],
                              'Allocation Type':['Historical','Historical','Predicted', 
                                                  'Predicted','Predicted','Historical']})
print (df_HA_noHA_act)
#[6000 rows x 2 columns]
df_HA_noHA_act = pd.concat([df_HA_noHA_act]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [187]: %%timeit
     ...: df_HA_noHA_act['Flag1'] = np.where((df_HA_noHA_act["Allocation Type"] == 'Predicted') & (df_HA_noHA_act['Activities_Counter'] >= 10), 'Flag', '')
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 1.89 ms per loop

In [188]: %%timeit
     ...: Flag = []
     ...: for i, row in df_HA_noHA_act.iterrows():
     ...:     if (row['Activities_Counter'] >= 10) and (row["Allocation Type"] == 'Predicted'):
     ...:         Flag.append('Flag')
     ...:     else:
     ...:         Flag.append('')
     ...: df_HA_noHA_act['Flag'] = Flag
     ...: 
     ...: 
1 loop, best of 3: 381 ms per loop
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you so much :)

Comment: Are timings a component of computer science where you can get your code to run faster?

Comment: I think it is fastest solution, I test it in my PC.